# Redux in Typescript doesn't check types

Tags: typescript, redux

I followed a manual at https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript

Here is type definition for Redux. I set title variable type to boolean, which should accept only true or false.

```
export interface MarkdownData {
    title: boolean;
}

export interface MarkdownState {
    data: MarkdownData;
}

export const MARKDOWN_SUCCESS = "MARKDOWN_SUCCESS";

interface FetchSuccessAction {
    type: typeof MARKDOWN_SUCCESS;
    payload: MarkdownData;
}

export type MarkdownActionTypes = FetchSuccessAction;
```

This is reducer.. I simply assign payload to data.

```
import {
  MarkdownState,
  MARKDOWN_SUCCESS,
  MarkdownActionTypes
} from '../types/markdown';

const initialState: MarkdownState = {
  data: {
    title: false
  }
};

export default function (state = initialState, action: MarkdownActionTypes): MarkdownState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MARKDOWN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In action, I then try to store params to redux states.

```
export function fetchSuccess(response:MarkdownData): MarkdownActionTypes {
  console.log("Response contents : ", response)
  return {
    type: MARKDOWN_SUCCESS,
    payload: response
  };
}
```

Here is console.log output in fetchSuccess() function right above,

```
Response contents :  {
  title: 'my-app',
}
```

Strange thing is that there is no error in this app when trying to assign this string value 'my-app' to title variable, which is supposed to only accept boolean type. The entire app works fine and generates no error or warning.

How can I fix it so that typescript can deny assigning string value to boolean variable?

---

ADDED:

```
export const fetchMD_Homepage = (site: string) => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  if (!site) {
    return
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/markdown/Homepage`)
    const items:MarkdownData = await response.json()
    dispatch(fetchSuccess(items))
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(fetchError(err))
  }
}
```

I call fetchSuccess() functions like this.

If I change "dispatch(fetchSuccess(items))" to "dispatch(fetchSuccess({title:"ddw"}))", then yes, it does print an error that I cannot assign string to boolean.

Comment: Can you show your async logic that is dispatching `fetchSuccess` in the first place?

Comment: @markerikson sorry, added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is *you* have asserted that `items` is a `MarkdownData` type, and *you* have told TS that that type contains a boolean.  TS has no way of knowing what the actual return type from `fetch()` is, so if the API response contains a string when you said a field should be a boolean, TS can't know about that and won't prevent that code from running.  From its perspective, the data is the right type, therefore the code to use that data is correct.  It's the difference between compile-time types and run-time types.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript only checks types at compile time, it is not checking types at runtime. Typescript can't know the type of the response from a `fetch` request, that's why you have to declare the type of the response (as you do - currently you declare it to be of type `MarkdownData`). Typescript can't do anything about the actual type of the response at runtime.